# Failed to execute the cache operation (all partition owners are left the grid partition data has been lost)

Tags: .net, ignite

I have .Net Ignite client and server app Ignite v2.9.1. we have a 2 node
cluster,
recently we are upgraded ignite 2.7.6 to ignite 2.9.1 after using this
the version we are facing issues frequently.

```
[2021-02-02T10:09:15,668][ERROR][client-connector-#227%ServerNode%][ClientListenerNioListener] Failed to process client request [req=o.a.i.i.processors.platform.client.cache.ClientCacheGetRequest@bb5fb96]
javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheInvalidStateException: Failed to execute the cache operation (all partition owners have left the grid, partition data has been lost) [cacheName=CREDENTIALS, partition=759, key=UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=759, val=SqlCredentialAdo-Althing-energyapp, hasValBytes=false]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.convertToCacheException(GridCacheUtils.java:1270) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.cacheException(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:2083) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.get(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1110) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.get(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:676) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.client.cache.ClientCacheGetRequest.process(ClientCacheGetRequest.java:41) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.client.ClientRequestHandler.handle(ClientRequestHandler.java:99) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener.onMessage(ClientListenerNioListener.java:202) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener.onMessage(ClientListenerNioListener.java:56) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:279) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:109) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter$3.body(GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter.java:97) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorkerPool$1.run(GridWorkerPool.java:70) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheInvalidStateException: Failed to execute the cache operation (all partition owners have left the grid, partition data has been lost) [cacheName=CREDENTIALS, partition=759, key=UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=759, val=SqlCredentialAdo-Althing-energyapp, hasValBytes=false]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtTopologyFutureAdapter.validateKey(GridDhtTopologyFutureAdapter.java:209) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtTopologyFutureAdapter.validateCache(GridDhtTopologyFutureAdapter.java:128) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.validate(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:859) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.map(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:277) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.init(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:244) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.getAsync0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1471) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.access$1600(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:141) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$16.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:477) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$16.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:475) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.asyncOp(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:779) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.getAsync(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:475) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.get(GridCacheAdapter.java:4844) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.repairableGet(GridCacheAdapter.java:4810) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.get(GridCacheAdapter.java:1469) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.get(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1107) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have backups configured on that cache? Do you have persistence enabled? If you don't, and it's OK to acknowledge the loss of data, you can try to [reset lost partitions](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/partition-loss-policy):

```
bin/control.sh --cache reset_lost_partitions CREDENTIALS
```

Comment: yes I enabled persistence but backups are not enabled

Comment: Then you need to reset lost partitions after you restart a node, since some partitions were lost for some period of time.

Comment: Hi, Alamar thanks for your replay,
In our case, server nodes are always online and there is no server node
downtime until we make it manually. So am wondering how are partitions getting lost
frequently? and if this error occurred read and write operations will not
work with the respective cache.

Comment: Please provide logs from some server node. You can also only select "Topology snapshot" messages from it. I think there will be server nodes coming and leaving.

Comment: @alamar I've got the same error and I did have persistence enabled on the cache. What piece of logs/configuration should I check first?

Comment: @AlexAvrutin perhaps you should check your baseline topology to see which nodes are and aren't available.

Comment: @alamar Thank you. As far as I remember all the nodes included into BT were available. I did read somewhere while I was investigating the error that it's common for Ignite to report partitions as lost after a node containing the partition went offline, even though later it came online and had all the data on the disk available. Is it true? If it is, it is possible to avoid that somehow? It's not particularly convenient to run the Control utility to "reset" lost partitions when no data was actually lost (since a partition with persistence enabled is supposed to be durable).

Comment: I suggest asking another question about that.